# Error al instalar docker desktop 4.26.1

Tags: docker

Me sale este error en la instalacion de docker, alguien me puede apoyar por favor

Component Docker.Installer.EnableFeaturesAction failed: No encontrado
en Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

Mi equipo tiene Windows 10 Pro, tengo 8 gb ram y 70 gb de espacio en disco.